# Finite groups with unique minimal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $G$ has a unique non trivial minimal subgroup. Then $G$ is a p-group. How to prove the theorem which says that: If $G$ has a unique non trivial minimal subgroup and if $p$ is not 2, then $G$ is cyclic. I made several attempts but failed eventually. The theorem is false for $p=2$ as shown in one of the answers.

Comment: I suppose you mean a unique minimal _non-trivial_ subgroup. And also minimal in the sense that it is contained in any non-trivial subgroup?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen usually "minimal blank subgroup" or "maximal blank subgroup" are interpreted in the non-trivial sense (ie, if blank is always satisfied by all subgroups, then one does not need to specify proper or non-trivial. But if not all subgroups need to satisfy it, then one would need to). So for example, minimal normal includes non-trivial, but maximal nilpotent could potentially be the entire group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: That seems a reasonable convention, although I've never seen it stated so explicitly. But you should formulate a bit more precise: "minimal (qualified) subgroup" implicitly includes "non-trivial" if $\{e\}$ always satisfies the qualification, and "maximal (qualified) subgroup" implicitly includes "proper" if the whole group always satisfies the qualification. In your example _not_ all subgroups are always normal, but $\{e\}$ and the whole group are always so, whence the non-trivial/proper is nonetheless implied by "minimal normal" or "maximal normal".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Ahh, of course. My version was not quite right. I don't think I have seen it stated anywhere explicitly either, it is simple my experience that the terms are used like this.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite see a very easy way to show this. The way I know involves taking a minimal counterexample and noting that this will have a cyclic subgroup of index $p$. Then one uses the classification of these to see that it does not hold there (the same method shows that the generalized quaternion groups are the only counterexamples). It might be possible to only do a fraction of that classification to get to this result though, as we are only looking at minimal subgroup, not unique sungroup of some other given order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "theorem" is false by any interpretation. The [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$ is not cyclic, but has a unique minimal non-trivial subgroup $\{1,-1\}$; it is contained in any non-trivial subgroup of$~Q_8$. (And of course if "minimal subgroup" means $\{e\}$, then *any* non-cyclic group is a counterexample.)

Comment: Ah! you are right, but I changed the question a liitle bit.

Comment: As $p=2$ always behaves strangely, the theorem is false for $p=2$. The theorem is true for other primes $p$.